# Change an Active Directory password

Tags: c#, active-directory, passwords

At first, please forgive my English, it is not my mother tongue.

I'm working on a web platform that manages Active Directory. I can create, delete and edit a group, user, OU, and so on.

When a connected user wants to change his own password with the platform, it fails.

It comes from `DirectoryEntry.Invoke`.

I used the `DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`:

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", password);
directoryEntry.Commit();
```

So I tried System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Username);
user.SetPassword(password_);
user.Save();
```

Different way, same problem.

It only fails when a user tries to edit his own password.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paolo notes, you can't call Reset Password without extra privileges. To call ChangePassword, you need to supply the previous password like this:

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", oldPassword, newPassword); 
directoryEntry.Commit();
```

Comment: I've tried this code when Paolo suggest it, and the result is the same: .Invoke issue. And and I use the DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, the error says that I have to check password policies (length, complexity, etc). And I have disabled them. So, the issue could be with ACE and the permission  of changing his own password by programming.

Comment: I've tried to edit the ACE, using SecurityDescriptor, AccessControlList and so on and it fails. It happens often with it: "The security ID structure is invalid". I tried with PrincipalContext and its method UserCannotChangePassword = false, explained here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761312/active-directory-properties) or here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it seems to be useless.

Comment: The occured error is the same than here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946150/security-id-structure-invalid-getting-this-error-when-setting-the-new-securityd but the solution does not work for me .

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It works for me,

```
public void ChangeMyPassword(string domainName, string userName, string currentPassword, string newPassword)
{
    try
    {
        string ldapPath = "LDAP://192.168.1.xx";
        DirectoryEntry directionEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, domainName + "\\" + userName, currentPassword);
        if (directionEntry != null)

        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(directionEntry);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                if (userEntry != null)
                {
                    userEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { currentPassword, newPassword });
                    userEntry.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow worked for me too first try!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows restriction: a user cannot reset his own password, i.e. change the password without providing the old one.

You can only change your own password, i.e. provide old password and new password.
Try using the `ChangePassword` method instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, and it fails. When using DirectoryEntry, it results the same .Invoke issue. And when I use the PrincipalContext way, the error says that I have to check password policies (length, complexity, etc). And I have disabled them. O.o

Answer (score 0):

Change Password requires user's old password to set new password and Reset password permission requires to the person who resets the password.With AD's default             permissions, only Administrators and Account Operators can reset passwords.